# Movie после инициализации остается null

Tags: gif, android

Хочу вывести gif файл в movie, gif хранится на sdcard. Объект movie пробовал создать по разному, т.е. `decodestream/decodefile/decodebytearray`, но без результатно - 
movie после этих операций равен null. Если брать gif из ресурсов, то тем же decodestream объект movie создается.

Вот мой код:

```
public GifView(Context context, InputStream inputStream) {
    super(context);
    gifInputStream = inputStream;
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context){
    setFocusable(true);        
    gifMovie = Movie.decodeStream(gifInputStream);
    movieWidth = gifMovie.width();
    movieHeight = gifMovie.height();
    movieDuration = gifMovie.duration();
}
```

GifView это наследуемый от View класс, в него через конструктор передается stream. Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: а разрешение на чтение с SD карты есть?

Comment: Да, разрешение на чтение SD есть - у меня, кроме этого, gif другие изображения показываются из этого каталога.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте отключить аппаратное ускорение - добавить `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` в Activity в AndroidManifest.xml

У Movie достаточно ограниченная и не везде работающая поддержка gif. Воспользуйтесь лучше сразу готовой библиотекой. Мне нравится [android-gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable). Есть ещё [GifImageView](https://github.com/felipecsl/GifImageView) и другие.